# Continuous Functions with Domain the Closed Interval [a,b]

Tags: real-analysis

Problem: Let $f$ be a continuous function whose domain includes the closed interval [$a$,$b$]. If $f(a)$ $\lt$ $0$ and $f(b)$ $\gt$ $0$, then there is a number $x$ between $a$ and $b$ such that $f(x)$ = $0$

Proof:

Let $f$ be a continuous function whose domain includes the closed interval [$a$,$b$]

Let $f(a)$ $\lt$ $0$ and $f(b)$ $\gt$ $0$

Then if $S$ is *any* open interval containing the number $f(x)$, then there is an open interval $T$ containing the number $x$ such that if $t$ $\in$ $T$, and $t$ is in the domain of $f$, then $f(t)$ $\in$ $S$ (our class' defintion of continuous)

Then it has a left-most point $a$ and a right-most point $b$

I'm not sure where to go from here. I need to show that there is a number $x$ between $a$ and $b$ such that $f(x)$ = $0$

Comment: Let $c = \sup\{x \in [a,b] : f(x) < 0\}$ and see what $f(c)$ should be.

Comment: This is my first theoretical math class and my teacher has not defined "sup" ever. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: The problem you have mentioned is famous by the name *Intermediate Value Theorem* and you can find ample proofs and discussions on this topic via Google and by searching on this site. You may also have a look at my [blog post](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/06/continuous-functions-on-closed-interval-intermediate-value-theorem.html). Ideally this should not be given as a problem, but rather discussed in class with all the details.

Answer (score 1):

According to your "class" definition of continuous, you could come up with the following solution :

Since the set $C = \{x\in [a,b]  : f(x) < 0\}$ is bounded, it must have a least upper bound(roughly, a number which is greater than every element of $C$, but is the smallest number with that property). If you like I can elaborate here.

Let $c$ be that least upper bound(also called the supremum and denoted $c = \sup C$). We claim $f(c) = 0$.

What if $f(c) < 0$? Then let $S$ be the interval $\left(\frac{3f(c)}{2},\frac{f(c)}{2}\right)$. Note that $S$ contains strictly negative numbers. Now, we know that there is an interval $T$ around $c$ which is such that if $t \in T$ then $f(t) \in S$. Now, an interval around $c$ contains at least one point larger than $c$, say $c_0$, but then $f(c_0) < 0$ so $c_0 \in C$. This contradicts the fact that $c$ was the supremum of $C$.

Similarly, I leave you to see that $f(c) > 0$ will also lead to a contradiction. Hence, you can conclude that $f(c) = 0$. Clearly, $c \in (a,b)$ since $c < b$.

Comment: Just to add, as Paramanand Singh mentioned earlier, this is a very classical result, caled Bolzano's theorem or the precursor to the intermediate value theorem, and should be discussed in class. Also, the supremum of a *upper bounded set*, is the smallest number with the property that it is larger than every number of that set. For example, the supremum of $(1,2)$ would be $2$, since it's larger than every number in $(1,2)$, but is also the smallest number with this property. Similarly, $\sup\{1,2,3,4\} = 4$. But  the supremum of, say $\mathbb N$ does not exist.